# iPad WebApp: Transition button not working above video

Tags: ipad, html, web-applications, html5-video, css-transitions

I have an issue with HTML5 video and transition.
I clearly see the two transition buttons I made above the video but I can't click on it.
It seems that the video captures the click.

Does anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, I have seen video elements swallow clicks when controls attribute is present. Try removing controls attr, and then re-adding it when video starts.

Comment: The thing is, I want the button to be always clickable, so I think I need something something to remove controls attr in specific areas of the video.
But I don't know how can I do that.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Example: You have two transition button to switch between your slides (in HTML5) which are above your video and you want to click on them whatever if the video is playing or not.